# Problem with Fischer-Riesz Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

> $\forall F \in H^* \exists! y \in H \mbox{ such that } F(x)= \left \langle x,y \right \rangle $

Suppose $F \neq 0$. Let be $$M=KerF.$$
$M$ is a closed vector space.
Let be $h \in M^{\bot}$ with $\left \| h \right \|=1$. So $F(h)=1$, and consider $F(h)x-F(x)h$. This element is in $M$ because $F(F(h)x-F(x)h)=0$.
So:
$$ 0= \left \langle F(h)x-F(x)h,h \right \rangle=F(h) \left \langle x,h \right \rangle-F(x) \left \langle h,h \right \rangle.$$
So I have:
$$F(x)= \left \langle x,h \right \rangle F(h).$$
This implies that $dim M^{\bot}=1$

Why this implication? I understood the rest of the proof, but I don't understand this implication.

After I can say that $\forall x \in H$ I can write $x= \lambda h + w$ where $h \in M^{\bot}$ and $w \in M$ and using $F$, I find that $\lambda =\frac{F(x)}{F(h)}$ and I continue the proof taking $y=F(h)h$ obtaining  the thesis.

Someone can explain me that implication? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the representation $F(x)=\langle x,h\rangle F(h)$ (bearing in mind that $F(h)\not=0$), you know that $F(x)=0$ if and only if $x\perp h$; that is, $ M=\{h\}^\perp$.

Comment: Maybe you mean $M=<h>^{\bot}$?

Comment: Indeed I do mean the orthogonal complement of the span of $h$.  Thanks!